Android Studio: Ошибка hzy.n7zip
У меня возникла ошибка при компиляции Gradle, ошибка такова:
"Failed to resolve: com.hzy:un7zip:1.7.1<a href ='open.dependency.in.project.structure"
И дальше путь к файлу Build.scripts module: app.
Версию менял, градл тоже менял. Была подобная ошибка на других исходниках "com.hzy:libp7zip:1.7.0".
Перепробовал уже 4-5 исходников — ошибка та же.

Они опубликованы в репозитории jcenter, который уже несколько лет как закрыт. Ищите другие источники или библиотеки.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Скачайте лучше последний доступный AAR и используйте его в проекте.
https://github.com/hzy3774/AndroidP7zip/releases/tag/v1.7.1
А еще лучше найдите другую библиотеку, эта очень похоже что заброшена автором.
Как добавить AAR в проект?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-gradle-for-android
